# Can Data-agent opscenter use cassandra native port?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I tried to shift cassandra listener from rpc port to native port. However, after I turn off rpc port, opscenter would not work. I had to start both native and rpc port.

Is there any way let opscenter use native port? Also, if cassandra listerns on both native and rpc port, is there any performance penalty?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what version of OpsCenter you are using. Prior to version 5.2, it requires the Thrift RPC port. 5.2+ uses only native transport so you could disable Thrift.

That said, having both open will only use a marginal amount of additional memory, and you should not see any performance penalty having both servers bound.